# How to convert this formula into an arrayformula? Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Been beating my head against this and can't get it. Here is the forumla:

```
=IF(E3=E2,F2,F2+1)
```

Pretty simple. All it does is look at the cell above it...if they are the same it doesn't increase the number iteration. If they are different it does. Somehow I can't figure out how to format this in order to make it an ArrayFormula. The only reason I want it to be an Arrayformula is so that rows can be added or removed and the formula would remain intact thus the spreadsheet would be easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to place it in column F from F3, you may try another approach or you'll get a circular dependency:

```
=BYROW(E3:E,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",F2+sum(MAP(E3:each, LAMBDA(c,IF(c="","",IF(c=OFFSET(c,-1,),0,1))))))))
```

Comment: This did something, but the numbers are all jank. Doesn't really work the way I want it to. I guess maybe I'll explain more? Like If the names are "bus, bus, car, train, train, plane, plane, plane" then the corresponding numbers should be "1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4" ya see? Each new name encountered should increase the value by +1.

Comment: I don't know where it could be junk, but you could try to make it a running count in F2: =BYROW(E2:E,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",COUNTA(UNIQUE(E2: each)))))

Comment: In my first answer you just have to reverse the order of 1 and 0 in the end of the formula to work that way. I'll edit the answer so you can have both options. Remember that the first answer works from F3, and this second answer works from F2

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(BYROW(E2:INDEX(E:E, MAX(ROW(E:E)*(E:E<>""))), 
 LAMBDA(e, IF(OFFSET(e, 1, )=e, OFFSET(e,,1), OFFSET(e,,1)+1))
```